# How to use Postman for Laravel $_POST request

Tags: laravel, postman

How can I try sending a post request to a Laravel app with Postman?

Normally Laravel has a `csrf_token` that we have to pass with a POST/PUT request. How can I get and send this value in Postman? Is it even possible *without turning off* the CSRF protection?

Comment: But, well if you really really want the csrf_token you can make a get request to a route and then manually insert the token generated in postman. [Not really a solution]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Edit:

Ah wait, I misread the question. You want to do it without turning off the CSRF protection? Like Bharat Geleda said: You can make a route that returns only the token and manually copy it in a `_token` field in postman.

But I would recommend excluding your api calls from the CSRF protection like below, and addin some sort of API authentication later.

*Which version of laravel are you running?*

### Laravel 5.2 and up:

Since 5.2 the CSRF token is only required on routes with `web` middleware. So put your api routes outside the group with `web` middleware.

See the "The Default Routes File" heading in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing) for more info.

### Laravel 5.1 and 5.2:

You can exclude routes which should not have CSRF protection in the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware like this:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/*',
    ];
}
```

See the "Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection" heading [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris) for more info.

Comment: thanks, yeah that makes more sense, for API instead of CSRF, using authentication is the best option

Comment: Can't get this to work in Laravel 5.5. Postman just showing "page has expired due to inactivity"- which means the token is rejected / or not working..?

Comment: @Inigo That is the new page for TokenException, so your token is rejected. Probably because your sessions are not working properly. Check if your storage folder is writable for sessions.

Comment: @Hilmanrdn: Bit late to the game, but I'd recommend using both — they're designed to solve completely different security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 16):

If you store your sessions in Cookies, you can grab the Cookie from an auth request in Developer Tools.

[image]

Copy and paste that Cookie in the Header of your POSTMAN or Paw requests.

[image]

This approach allows you to limit your API testing to your current session.

Comment: i got CSRF token mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can create a new route to show the csrf token using your controller with help of the function below.
(Use a Get request on the route)

```
   public function showToken {
      echo csrf_token(); 

    }
```

2.Select the Body tab on postman and then choose x-www-form-urlencoded.
3.Copy the token and paste in postman as the value of the key named _token.
4.Execute your post request on your URL/Endpoint

Answer (score 1):

In the headers, add the cookies, before making request, the XSRF-TOKEN cookie and the app cookie. I.e yourappname_session

Answer (score -3):

In laravel, 5.3. Go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` find `middlewareGroups` then comment VerifyCsrfToken. Because it executes all middleware before service your request.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
            'web' => [
                \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
               ***// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,***
                \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            ],

            'api' => [
                'throttle:60,1',
                'bindings',
            ],
        ];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Reason is that in post request laravel 5.3 check csrf token. After commenting this line we prevent application for csrf token verification.

Comment: This is a bad idea because now ALL your routes are without CSRF protection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: Disabling it for API routes is ok because you can implement authentication for these routes which protects them again.