# getting error when i use poster to post value in laravel 5.1 but work right by form using method post

Tags: php, laravel, poster

I am getting error when I use poster to post in laravel 5.1 project but it work 
right with form by using method post

[image]

Comment: It returns a 500 error, but if you look at the error returned which is most likely in that textarea starting at `<!DOCTYPE html>` then it should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest disabling it, just add it to your request ;).

Comment: ans: to use poster to post in laravel 5.1 you have to first disable csrf_token protection for that route.    You can exclude routes which should not have CSRF protection in the VerifyCsrfToken middleware like this:    
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        't',
    ];
}  ref=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137768/how-to-use-postman-for-laravel-post-request