# token mismatch exception android webservices?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working laravel 5.2. I got this error while making webservice of android 
i justmake one webservice of login but it shows me error on postman 
**TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:**
 I know how to handle in the webpage pass the hidden field of csrf_token but i don't know how tohandle in the webservices can anyone help me
here is my code:-

```
enter code here
public function user_login(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $userdata = $request->all();
        echo 'cvdasvc';
        unset($userdata['_token']);
        $checkUserExist = User::where(['mobile'=>$userdata['mobile'],'password'=>$userdata['password']])->first();
        if(!empty($checkUserExist)){
            $message = "Login Successfully!";
            $userdata = $checkUserExist;
        }else{
            $message = "wrong Creditanls!";
            $userdata = array();
        }
        echo json_encode(array(
            'message' =>$message,
            'data'=> $userdata
            )
        ); die;

    }
}
```

Comment: [how-to-use-postman-for-laravel-post-request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137768/how-to-use-postman-for-laravel-post-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Laravel 5.4, CSRF protection is disabled by default for the API routes. (All API routes should be inside routes/api.php for that)

But as you are using Laravel 5.2 which don't have such feature, you can do it like this:

Prefix all of your webservice routes with an identifier like 'api':

route.php:

```
Route::post('api/test1', function() { 
  return 'test1'; 
});

Route::post('api/test2', function() { 
  return 'test2'; 
});
```

and then add this in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:

```
protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];
```