# How to access inputted token value - Laravel API

Tags: laravel, jwt, token, laravel-8, rest

[image]

I am inputting a token as above and trying to print the token value with the below code. But getting error `Undefined variable: token`. I'm not sure whether i can access the token as below. Pls help me with ur suggestions.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Files;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FileController extends Controller
{
  public function upload()
    {
       $tock=Auth::user()->$token;
       dd($tock);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will solve your problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137768/how-to-use-postman-for-laravel-post-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137768/how-to-use-postman-for-laravel-post-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the `$token` variable on the user, even though it does not exist.

Instead you should by trying to access the `request` and the values that are send with the request. This can be achieved using the `request()` helper or by injecting the Request class into the function.

With injection:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Files;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // Add request to namespace
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FileController extends Controller
{
  public function upload(Request $request)
    {
       dd($request->bearerToken());
    }
}
```

Or, without injection:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Files;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FileController extends Controller
{
  public function upload()
    {
       dd($request->bearerToken());
    }
}
```

With the `bearerToken()` method you can access the Bearer token provided in the request.

Comment: what if i need the id of the user which is not an inputting field ? when i tried `Auth::user()->id; `, i got the error `trying to get id of a non object`

Comment: The error tells you that `Auth::user()` is not an object. Therefore, you can not call ID of non object.

You need to find a way to identify and authorize the user. I am assuming you are using a packake for this. If so, what package are you using?

Comment: am using only the `Auth` package

Comment: Okay! I think you should research the authentication method of the user for the API. The `Auth` package is (generally) used for the `web ` routes. Currently, your user is not identified by the bearerToken. How does the system know what bearerToken belongs to what user, and decide whether that user should get access?

Laravel 7.X and up has access to [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum). Try and read the docs, do some research and try implementing it! Perhaps opening a new question is better if you run into any future problems.